# saving a 3 dimensional array

Tags: arrays, r, save

Working R I have a 81 by 81 by 81 array of numbers between 0 and 1, because it takes so long to generate the array I would like to save and reload it, but I have tried write.csv and save but I get a 81 by 6561 object returned. Can I either save it as a 3 dim array, or unpack it from a 2 dim array? 
Thanks.

Comment: `save(three_d_variable_name, file="3d.Rda")` then, later, `load("3d.Rda")`

Comment: @hrbrmstr - add that as an answer. I can't think of a better way to save such an object. If it has to be human readable, just use `?dump`

Comment: I was also thinking to save the output of `dput` to a file then load it back up with `eval`, but the rda files are soooo compact, esp if you use `compress`.

Comment: @hrbrmstr - `dget` can load the `dput` object.  `dput(x, "d.txt"); dget("d.txt")`

Comment: Heh. I only ever use `dput` to edit posts here. Good to know.

Answer (score 3):

You can use R's `save` and `load` functions to save our your built objects. I do that quite a bit with API responses (some are huge & complex and take a considerable amount of query time):

```
save(three_d_variable_name, file="3d.Rda")
```

To load it back int the environment (with the same variable name):

```
load("3d.Rda")
```

Comment: Both very helpful, thank you, I was stuck because I used abc<-load("3d.Rda"), that doesn't assign the data to abc, but the data is reloaded as three_d_variable_name, which I discovered by deleting it in between. Thanks again, Gayle.